# Latex align table within itemize

Tags: tables

I am trying to write my CV using latex. I have the following problem. I want a table within itemize environment. This is how my code looks:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\section*{Conferences}

\begin{itemize}

    \item Oral presentation

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}

     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, New Orleans & Dec \lq13 \\

     YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY & Mar \lq13 \\

     ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ, Krakow & Jul \lq11 \\

    \end{tabularx}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I want the list of conferences to be left aligned with oral presentation and YYY conference to be wrapped.

I did not yet try out \moderncv or other cv latex templates.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're asking for:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{25pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section*{Conferences}

\begin{itemize}

    \item Oral presentation

    \hspace{-\tabcolsep}\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xr}

     A conference title, New Orleans & Dec \lq13 \\

     Slightly longer conference title, some other place & Mar \lq13 \\

     A hideously long conference title which has no sense, but does demonstrate line wrapping just fine, Krakow & Jul \lq11 \\

    \end{tabularx}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I.e. using `\hspace{-\tabcolsep}` to get rid of the white space latex inserts as left and right 'margins' within cells.

Alternatively using `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xr@{}}` also removes the additional whitespace at the right hand side - thx to @DavidCarlise for that.

That said, though - I would strongly recommend using one of those templates you mentioned.

Comment: `\hspace` better than `\hskip` in latex (or just suppress tabcolsep with `@{}`)  also the tabular line is still overfull as it's specified to be `\textwidth` wide but is indented in the enumerate. (should be `\linewidth`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thx, you're right about the `linewidth` and `hspace` of course - the `@{}` seems to also swallow the indentation given by being within `itamize` though.

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xr@{}}` works for me

Comment: @DavidCarlisle right it does - my bad in testing before. added another comment to my answer.